# Retrieve secrets from AWS Secrets manager in Confluent ksqlDB

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, ksqldb, aws-secrets-manager, confluent-cloud

I am trying to create in **Confluent Cloud** (Kafka) a MongoDB **connector sink with ksqlDB**. The problem is that I have the data source and credentials in the AWS Secrets manager.

Is there a way to obtain the secrets with ksqlDB to set the connector properties?

Answer (score 0):

Kafka Connect supports [Externalized config](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/security.html#externalizing-secrets) for secrets. Whether such an implement exists for AWS, I am not sure, but if not, you'll need to write your own `ConfigProvider` for it.

Alternatively, there may be alternative solutions like running ksql or just Connect itself in MSK Connect, ECS, EC2, or EKS where you write processes around exposing Secrets Manager data into files or environment variables, which can then be used by Connect's default config providers, then setup ksql externally to point at those Connect instances, or just process the topics it outputs